# Python set sequence of numbers to add or subtract for certain result

Tags: python, algorithm, math, sequence, iterable

In this hypothetical scenario I have a **sequence** of numbers of known, but random length and I need to set each number in the sequence to **add** or **subtract** to reach a given output and show the process.

Is there a way to do this without reinventing the wheel, such as a module?

EDIT: More Info:

I have a sequence of numbers like: 5 4 3 2 1 and I need to set each number to add (+) or subtract (-) to get a result such as 7. The result in this case would be 5+4-3+2-1. It could be a sequence of any numbers as far as there is a possible result. If there are multiple correct answers just one of them will do.

Edit:

> Let's assume that no step in the equation results in an answer larger than 1000.

Comment: This needs to be less hypothetical.  Gives us some example data and explain what you want.

Comment: Addressed the issue.

Comment: I'd love to see a mathematician name the theorem for that.. can't remember now !

Comment: If you are looking for an algorithm with better time complexity than @Kevin's below that isn't python specific, http://cs.stackexchange.com is probably the more appropriate venue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach is to just brute-force all possible combinations of plus and minus, and return the first one that has the correct sum. You can use `itertools.product` to do this.

```
import itertools

def find_correct_operators(seq, total):
    signs = [-1,1]
    for item_signs in itertools.product(*[signs]*len(seq)):
        seq_with_signs_applied = [item*sign for item, sign in zip(seq, item_signs)]
        sum(seq_with_signs_applied)
        if sum(seq_with_signs_applied) == total:
            return item_signs

a = [5,4,3,2,1]
b = 7
signs = find_correct_operators(a,b)
if signs is not None:
    print "{} = {}".format(" ".join("{}{}".format("-" if sign == -1 else "+", item) for sign, item in zip(signs, a)), b)
else:
    print "No solution found"
```

Result:

```
+5 -4 +3 +2 +1 = 7
```

The drawback to this is that it runs in O(2^N) time, so it's highly unsuitable for any sequence of numbers larger than, say, twenty items long. By that point, you're iterating through more than a million possible combinations.

---

Edit: if you have some limit *L* and no intermediary step in the equation may ever evaluate to larger than L or smaller than -L, then you can find the answer in O(N*L) time, which is a considerable improvement for smallish values of L.

```
seq = [5,4,-3,2,1]
goal = 7
limit = 1000
d = {0: []}
for item in seq:
    next_d ={}
    for intermediary_total, path in d.iteritems():
        for candidate in [-item, item]:
            next_total = intermediary_total + candidate
            if abs(next_total) <= limit:
                next_d[next_total] = path + [candidate]
    d = next_d

if goal in d:
    print d[goal]
else:
    print "no solution found"
```

Result:

```
[5, 4, -3, 2, -1]
```

Comment: I was thinking of something a bit more complex but that seems to work !

Comment: The possible amount of numbers in the sequence is far too much to tackle it like that. Let's assume that no step in the equation results in an answer larger than 1000.

Comment: If there's also a _lower_ limit of -1000, that makes things easier... Edited.

Comment: I would like to add that in case someone is using Python 3 use d.items() instead of d.iteritems().